# Need to get time data about since when the instance was last stopped in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-logging

I want to get data on the stop time of an instance in gcp. i.e. since when an instance is stopped. I want to implement it in a script to use it further and move the server to snapshot. Can anyone help me with how to get this data from `gcp` either using `gcloud` or a python script calling google apis?

Answer (score 4):

To get the list of all compute instances with their last start and stop date and time.

`gcloud compute instances list --format='table(name,status,lastStartTimestamp,lastStopTimestamp.list())'`

Answer (score 0):

From the command bellow you can get the JSON data about stopped instances, changing the `timestamp` value accordingly:

```
gcloud logging read 'resource.type="gce_instance" AND logName:activity_log AND timestamp>="2019-08-27T00:00:00Z" AND jsonPayload.event_subtype:stop' --format json --project $project_id
```

Another way to get this kind of audit log information is using `logName:cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity` instead. For example, now considering a time range:

```
gcloud logging read 'resource.type="gce_instance" AND logName:"cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" AND timestamp>="2019-08-01T00:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2019-08-30T00:00:00Z" AND protoPayload.methodName:stop' --format json --project $project_id
```

Comment: This one also worked out for me but using `jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instances.stop"` instead of `jsonPayload.event_subtype="stop"`

Comment: @bhito I mentioned `jsonPayload.event_subtype:stop` which executes the "contains" approach instead of equals. As you mentioned, `="compute.instances.stop"` should work also.

Comment: I am not getting data for instances which are stopped 3-4 months ago, even though I put timestamp for 2018. Is there any time restriction?

Comment: @shreytyagi just updated my answer. Please check if this attends you